# Delete record which fields have specified values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to delete the record which has field with the specified by me values:

```
public static void delete(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
{
    try 
    {
        Statement myStmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "delete from students where firstName='" + firstName + "', lastName='" + lastName + "', age='" + age + "'";
        myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } 
    catch (SQLException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

The code does not work. I am absolutely sure that the problem in it. Help me to do the right sql, please. How can I find a record in table which fields have specified by me values?

Here is an error I am getting:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where firstName='deleted', lastName='deleted', age='10'' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2607)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1480)
    at Driver.delete(Driver.java:76)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:18)
```

Comment: does the record need to match all the values or either one of them

Comment: @FMashiro, all the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid all this syntax error or even SQL Injection you have to use PreparedStatement, so instead you can use :

```
String query = "delete from students where firstName=? and lastName=? and age=?";
try (PreparedStatement delete = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

    delete.setString(1, firstName);
    delete.setString(2, lastName);
    delete.setInt(3, age);//<-----------(1)

    delete.executeUpdate();
}
```

- (1) i'm not sure if the age is int or a varchar so if the age is an string you have to use setString instead.

---

Your real problem is that you have to use the `and`, `or` in the `where` instead of `,`

```
 where firstName='" + firstName + "', lastName='" + lastName + "', age='" + age + "'";
//----------------------------------^----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is incorrect, it should be:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM students WHERE firstName='" + firstName + "' AND lastName='" + lastName + "' AND age='" + age + "'";
```

You can only separate conditions in your `WHERE` clause by using keywords, such as `AND` or `OR` commas are invalid separators in that part of the SQL query.

Comment: Ok. Wait a moment I will try it out.

Comment: And use a `PreparedStatement` to avoid a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @AndrewS True, however I don't know Java enough to provide an answer with prepared statements. If you wish, you can post an example for OP